# Send Email in SAS to Multiple Recipients from Delimited String

Tags: sas

I have a table of data that I am trying to use SAS to send emails from. I am able to load the data in SAS and send an email for each row. But I am stuck trying to figure out how to convert a ';' delimited string into a macro variable with the appropriate structure.

Example of my source db table.

| NOTIFY_EMAILS | HTML_BODY |
| --- | --- |
| myemail@example.com; anotheremail@example.com | Some email text here |
| myemail@example.com | Another email I want to send |

I desire this to send 2 emails.

Here is the macro I've put together to send emails so far. It works great with a single email address, but is not dynamic to multiple email recipients.

```
%MACRO sendmail(NOTIFY_EMAILS, HTML_BODY);
    /*TODO: Somehow convert a delimited string into a macro variable for TO*/
    
    FILENAME snd EMAIL 'myemail@example.com' 
        TO=(&NOTIFY_EMAILS) 
        FROM='myemail@example.com'
        ct="text/html"
        REPLYTO=("myemail@example.com")
        SUBJECT="Email Alert";
    Data _null_;
        FILE snd;
    
        put '<html><body>';
        put "&HTML_BODY";
        put '</body></html>';
    run;
%mend ;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `tranwrd` to convert semicolons into commas.

```
data have;
    notify_emails = 'myemail@example.com; anotheremail@example.com';
    call symputx('notify_emails', tranwrd(notify_emails, ';', ',') );
run;

%put &notify_emails;
```

Output:

```
myemail@example.com, anotheremail@example.com
```

If your macro variable already exists, you can convert it directly. For example:

```
FILENAME snd EMAIL 'myemail@example.com' 
        TO=(%sysfunc(tranwrd(%superq(NOTIFY_EMAILS), %bquote(;), %bquote(,) ) ) )
...
```

Note that we need to use `%superq` since the macro variable contains a semicolon and we need to have it quoted after it is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up fixing my issue by formatting my email string in the form "email1" "email2" etc. Space delimited with quotes around each email. If I did not have direct SQL access like I do, I suspect Stu's answer above would be a great start to reformatting the strings.